# How to cause method calls enter a different method first

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, reflection

I don't even know how to properly title my question so any suggestions and I will change it. The problem I have is this; I have an object which has some dispose work to do. Using the "using" keyword and scope is not possible because the object can be in use for a long time. I do not want to rely on the programmer to remember call Dispose() on these objects because he might forget. Instead, I would want all or some methods of the object to work like this:

1. All the methods first go into some general function
2. This general function calls the original method
3. Depending on a bool param (for example) of the general method, the general method finished by maybe doing some cleanup work (disposing)

So if I have 10 methods, I would want them all to enter the same place, do their work, and then dispose. And I do not want to repeat the call to the dispose method in each of the 10 methods.

Example:

```
public void SomeBaseFunc(bool shouldDispose) //all methods first get drained here
{
//call whatever original func that the client called
//query bool param and dispose
}
```

Comment: _"I do not want to repeat the call to the dispose method in each of the 10 methods"_ - why not? That's less work than changing all call sites to `yourClass.Foo(yc => yc.OriginalMethod())`.

Comment: Hi. I'm not a C# expert, but I think that Aspect Oriented Programming can help you

Comment: `I do not want to rely on the programmer to remember call Dispose() on these objects because he might forget` Then fire him. Or rely on a finalizer like everyone else

Comment: The class should implement `IDisposable` and it's the consumer's *job* to remember to dispose it properly, with `using` or otherwise. That is part of a C# programmer's lot in life. If they forget, it's on them, not you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the scenario? With two decades of C# programming under my belt, I'm having a hard time imagining what the underlying problem is... Unless the object in question is handling some unmanaged code, in which case you should probably implement a finalizer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have not ten, but three methods in your class, the easiest way would be to modify their signature and have them call your "dispose but not really dispose" method:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public void Foo(int i, bool shouldDispose)
    {
        // Do the Foo(i) business

        DoTheDisposeOrNot(shouldDispose);
    }

    public void Bar(string s, bool shouldDispose)
    {
        // Do the Bar(s) business

        DoTheDisposeOrNot(shouldDispose);
    }
    
    public void Baz(bool b, bool shouldDispose)
    {
        // Do the Baz(b) business

        DoTheDisposeOrNot(shouldDispose);
    }
}
```

That's three modifications (the parameter) and three additions (the method call) and you're done.

On the call site, you modify `yourInstance.Foo(42)` to `yourInstance.Foo(42, true)` (or you give `shouldDispose` a sensible default value. You will need to recompile, or add an overload).

Now consider an alternative, where you move this responsibility to the caller. You could create a method like this:

```
public void SomeBaseFunc(Action<YourClass> action, bool shouldDispose)
{
    action(this);
    DoTheDisposeOrNot(shouldDispose);
}
```

And your caller will have to modify their call site anyway:

```
yourInstance.SomeBaseFunc(f => f.Foo(42), true);
```

Point is:

- It requires modification on the call site anyway
- It is ugly
- The caller can forget or refuse to do this modification, and the code will still call `yourInstance.Foo(42)`, omitting the dispose-call you wished to introduce

So, the answer is `Action<T>`, but the real answer is: add that parameter.